# Using C++ Boost Graph Library (BGL) in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, boost, delphi-7, boost-graph

In the large Delphi 7 project which I maintain, data is represented in a graph structure which takes an exponential amount of time to solve as the number of edges increases.

I know that the graph can be solved at a much higher rate using a function within the BGL, however, I do not believe that I can directly include the header (.hpp) into the project.

What are my options? Is there a way to include the header or do I need to look at rewriting at rewriting the required functionality in Pascal?

Comment: Wrap up the library and expose it as a DLL. Or find a Delphi implementation of this algo, whatever it actually is.

Comment: The DLL option sounds promising, do you think that this would incur significant communication overheads? The algorithm is push_relabel_max_flow, but I haven't found a Delphi implementation so far.

Comment: If the performance gain from switch algos is significant, the performance cost of calling a function in a DLL is trivial. It's just a function call. Nothing more.

Comment: [Rudy Velthuis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) of TeamB has written an article about [Using C++ Objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) that might help you here, but there's a lot more to using BGL than just wrapping a single function. It's hard for me to suggest an alternative, because you've not provided any information about what the function does specifically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Solve a graph"? That seems like a huge vague area in this question.

Comment: Ken, I understand that there will be a load of dependencies and includes if I try to wrap up this part of the BGL - do you think it would be possible to do though?

I didn't go into detail about the problem as I don't really think it's relevant to the question. Since you asked, I want to find the maximum flow in a network using the Goldberg push_relabel_max_flow function found in the Boost library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was easy to build a C++ DLL which exposed the required BGL functionality.

I found a simple example DLL project at http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/131058-example-dll-in-c-visual-studio/ and simply included the boost libraries within the project configuration.

My exposed function simply called the required BGL features and returned the result.